# How to set the order limit in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have to fix an order limit in Hybris, whereby the customer is not allowed to order more than a specific amount.

I was thinking of handling it in specific places, where the user can include items in the cart(i.e. on PDP and cart), but I think the promotions will have to be handled separately when the user tries to checkout.

Where is such a check recommended and is there a standard OOB approach?

Comment: I don't know if my answer reply your question, but this is what I understood from it.

Comment: @HamdiDouss,thanks a lot for your reply.Actually, I have to do it separately when on PDP page, when customer tries to add to cart and when updates quantity on the cart page.The scenario is becoming trickier with a lot of manual if checks.Is any better solution available here?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a validation on a checkout flow step.
For example, if you have a step after the cart entries validation (this is often the real start of the checkout), you can configure a validator to this step :

```
<bean id="MyFirstCheckoutStep" parent="checkoutStep">
    <property name="checkoutGroup" ref="myCheckoutGroup"/>
    <property name="checkoutStepValidator" ref="orderAmountLimitValidator"/>
    ...
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="orderAmountLimitValidator"
      class="com.site.checkout.steps.validation.impl.OrderAmountLimitValidator"
      parent="abstractCheckoutStepValidator"/>
```

Now you should implement your logic in the class `com.site.checkout.steps.validation.impl.OrderAmountLimitValidator` that should extend `AbstractCheckoutStepValidator` and return proper `ValidationResults` value.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.However, if I plan to apply this at PDP or cart level, and I have to take care of promotions(suppose a promotion is applied when this product is added), does it make sense to call the cart total and add the price of the upcoming request or add it to the cart and then check the price and delete it?

Comment: Normally promotions are only calculated in checkout, after the cart is finalized. It can make sense to "simulate" adding the product to the cart, do your calculus and then cancel that add if it doesn't fit the conditions.